# Why is NLog creating duplicate error messages?

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-core-mvc, nlog

NLog is set up to send me emails of all error messages that occur in my app.  It does the job, but I sometimes will get upward of a dozen duplicate emails letting me know of standard behaviors of the app (e.g. "User has updated listing" will occur once in the app and database but I will be notified 12+ times)

I can't find a rhyme or reason as to why certain messages are spamming my inbox while others behave as expected.  I notice it at all levels of logging and with varying numbers of duplicate error messages.

```
public static void Main(string[] args){    
    var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
        try
        {
            logger.Info("ProducersPortal.Web Started.");
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //NLog: catch setup errors
            logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            logger.Info("ProducersPortal.Web Stopped.");
            // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .UseNLog()  // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
            //.UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();


}
```

Above is the Program.cs file for my project.  I expect that NLog should only send one error message to my email at a time for each action I am logging, but instead I get various numbers of duplicate error messages.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting "duplicate" emails for a Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException from NLog:

- Once from the initial spot it was thrown which included a fragment of the full stack trace (starting at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.d__48.MoveNext())
- And another that included the full stack trace starting at the request - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext(). This was a much more useful message as it shows what controller action was called, the logic path it goes down, etc.

With the following snippet of code I was able to catch only the final error (from the second bullet above):

```
public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        NLog.LogManager.DisableLogging();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        NLog.LogManager.EnableLogging();
    }
}
```

As a side note I don't believe this solution works for every project configuration (e.g.: if there is an IExceptionFilter instance that sets context.ExceptionHandled = true the exception will never get caught by NLog).

Comment: Think it would be better to wrap the NLog-Mail-Target in NLog-BufferingWrapper with a timeout of 500 miliseconds. Then it would send single mail with multiple exceptions. See also https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/BufferingWrapper-target

Comment: @RolfKristensen - if that works I'm wondering why you've waited for someone else to come up with a solution and then down vote them? This question was asked 4 months ago. Not very nice. Also, I don't understand why 500 milliseconds is the "magic" number. Why not 250 or 750 milliseconds - seems like a fragile fix.

Comment: Your solution momentarily disables logging for all threads in the application. Thus critical logging might get lost for other requests. Also if some special situation occurs so `EnableLogging` is not called, then the entire application will suddenly become silent. The BufferingWrapper throttles logging, and 500 milliseconds ensures that you "only" get 2 emails per second. You can tweak the timeout to your needs.

Comment: Btw. I know very little about AspNetCore application, so I didn't know that the framework would by default log the same exception multiple times. To me the original question sounded like an invalid configuration of MEL or NLog. But if your explanation is true, then it is better to use BufferingWrapper instead of globally disabling logging momentarily (with all the side-effects it might have).

Comment: If you can verify that the BufferingWrapper will also resolve the issue with duplicate exceptions. And you update your answer with this solution, then I will happily vote you up.

Comment: @RolfKristensen I have verified that the BufferingWrapper approach works but the timeout number is "magic". I tested the bufferedMailTarget.FlushTimeout property with values of 500 and 750 which produced "duplicate" emails. 850 worked (at least locally). I understand that the "disable logging for all threads" seems problematic; however, I believe that this works in the web application I work on as everything goes thru the async/await pipeline and the error gets caught further down the pipeline/re-thrown at which point NLog has already been re-enabled.

Comment: @RolfKristensen https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs,ca9850c71672bd54

Comment: I guess if the web-application never handles requests concurrently then your pipeline-logic works. But when having 2 (or more) simultaneous requests, then your global-filter-logic fails (one request affects others). The "magic" timeout value depends on how fast your web-application handles the requests in the pipeline.

Comment: @RolfKristensen good point. I'm shocked NLog doesn't have a "per request configuration". Let's say I set the FlushTimeout to 5000 ms and two different users hit errors within that time frame. The emails we receive have a template which outputs a session ID and login information (if any). What does the email contain? The session ID/login information from the first error or the second one?

Comment: Yes sadly enough it only "groups" the logevents by the SmtpServer. Could be nice if it also respected the email-subject (Could include the userid in subject and ensure individual email). See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/899c3f51a681303855c21d03a17aa19cc5412e91/src/NLog/Targets/MailTarget.cs#L354 Guess you can create a feature request: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new/choose

Comment: Regarding your "shocked" effect then there is https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetBufferingWrapper-target for ASP.NET. But it is still missing for ASP.NET.Core: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/304 But the performance-issues and memory-allocation-issues might bite you later.